# Flutter Provider - Is provider Of method O(N)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I expected `Provider.of` method to be O(N) since i thought it would walk up the widget tree to find the closest provider. However, I looked at the provider [package document](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and it says:

> Or to use the static method Provider.of(context), which will behave similarly to watch/read
>
> These methods will look up in the widget tree starting from the widget
> associated with the BuildContext passed, and will return the nearest
> variable of type T found (or throw if nothing is found).
>
> It's worth noting that this operation is O(1). It doesn't involve
> actually walking in the widget tree.

I am so confused now. The documents say that its O(1) but how is this possible? Doesnt provider use flutter API's and they walk up the widget tree. Is there like a hashmap going on inside the provider package? I need to know this because I am using provider inside an frame by frame animation and my widget in deep in the tree. It might cause me performance issues.

Comment: Provider is O(1) for listening and reading values (`Provider.of`), but dispatching values (calling `notifyListeners()` in `ChangeNotifier` for example) it is O(N^2) where N is the number of listeners, (`context.watch` or `Consumer`)

Comment: Why is it O(N^2)? I believe it was O(N^2) before but it is optimized to O(N) now as flutter docs say its O(N), however provider packageay internally add things I'm not aware of

Comment: Docs for notifier say "It is O(1) for adding listeners and O(N) for removing listeners and dispatching notifications (where N is the number of listeners)."

Comment: Oh, then maybe I'm outdated...